# how to show labels in laravel charts when the name of the label is on another table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, chart.js, relationship

I have a permits table

```
    Schema::create('permits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('application_id')->unique();
        $table->string('type_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('state_id')->nullable();
```

it has one-to-one relationship with my state table

```
    Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
```

I want to make a chartjs in my view. In my controller I'm counting the number of permits grouped by their state_id

```
    $data = Permit::all()->groupBy('state_id')->map(function ($item) {
        return count($item);
    });
```

When making the labels for the chart, I can only pass the id and not the name, which is what I need for my chart.

```
    $chart = new PermitsChart;
    $chart->labels($data->keys());
```

Can anyone please help...

Comment: Are you trying to print the number of permits by state or the other way round? Also, if you have a 1:1 relation, your permit count for each state will be always 0 or 1, is that right? When you say that you can only print the id and not the name, do you mean the name of the state?

Comment: i can only show the id not the name for that state_id. I don't know how to connect the two

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set up the relationship between Permit and State models, and you want to count the number of permits for each state (so I think you meant to have a 1:N relation), you could do like this:

```php
$data = State::withCount('permits')->all();

// Then when you need to extract data
$chart = new PermitsChart;
$chart->labels($data->pluck('name'));

// To retrive the permit_count foreach state you can to
$data->pluck('permits_count'); // Array of counts
```

**Update**
To set up relationships between your model you have to add:

**Permit.php**

```php
class Permit extends Model
{
    // Your existing code
    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }
}
```

**State.php**

```php
class State extends Model
{
    // Your existing code
    public function permits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Permit::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then do not forget to mark the answer as correct! :)